# I'm trying to control a DAC61401 with an arduino UNO using SPI

Tags: arduino, spi, dac

I'm using the DAC61401 to a project where I want to be able to choose four different voltages from 0 to 22 volts, however, I can only get 0v. I was trying to control the DAC trough an arduino UNO using SPI.

The code I am using is the following:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

#define CS 10

inline void CSON()
{
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
}
inline void CSOFF()
{
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
}

void write_reg(uint8_t reg, uint16_t wdata)
{
  uint8_t lsb = ((uint16_t)wdata >> 0) & 0xFF;
  uint8_t msb = ((uint16_t)wdata >> 8) & 0xFF;
 
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(16000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0)); 
  CSON();
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  SPI.transfer(reg);
  SPI.transfer(msb);
  SPI.transfer(lsb);
  CSOFF();
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  SPI.endTransaction();
}


void setup() {
  pinMode(CS, OUTPUT); // set the CS pin as an output
  SPI.begin();         // initialize the SPI library
  Serial.begin(9600);
  write_reg(0x03, 0x0004);  //power up the device             ---> SPI_CONFIG
  write_reg(0x04, 0x0000);  //power up the internal reference ---> GEN_CONFIG
  write_reg(0x09, 0xFFFE);  //power up the DAC output         ---> DAC_PWDWN
  write_reg(0x0A, 0x000A);  //configure the DAC range (24v)   ---> DACRANGE
}



void loop() {
  write_reg(0x10, 0xEAB0);  //configure the VOUT to 22V        ---> DAC

  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Loop done");
}
```

I've checked the DAC's input voltages and they all seem to be correct.
Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: If you write to DEVICEID register with `write_reg(0x01, 0x0000);`, will you be able to get back the device id of `0x024c`? this will at least confirm that the communication between host and the sensor work with SPI before you are trying to do anything else.

Comment: How can I see the device id? Does the DAC send it to the Arduino through the spi communication? As I didn't know how to do that, I tried to write the id 0x024C to the DEVICE ID register but it still didn't solve the problem

Comment: It does not solve your problem, it helps you to debug it. Register 01 is DEVICEID register, the 0x024C is the id return from the chip that represent DAC61401 and software revision. Read page 29 of [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac61401.pdf). If this work, that means the SPI is working, problem is somewhere else. If it doesn't work, you have a problem with hardware....